# Appium : Getting error: opencv4nodejs module is required to use OpenCV features

Tags: node.js, opencv, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to use opencv4nodejs for image comparison with appium but getting the error.

**Version Information**

- System - mac
- OS : Catalina 10.15.7
- appium : CLI - 1.22.0
- node : v17.0.1
- npm : 8.1.0

**Set up done till now**

1. *export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1* -----in bash.profile
2. *npm install -g appium* ----- [Location : /usr/local/lib/node_modules]
3. *npm i -g opencv4nodejs*  ----- [Location : /usr/local/lib/node_modules]
4. went to appium folder using 'cd' ---- *npm link opencv4nodejs*  ----- [created link is displayed in appium folder]

**Error**

**1. In eclipse**

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'opencv4nodejs' module is required to use OpenCV features. Please install it first ('npm i -g opencv4nodejs') and restart Appium.

**2. On appium server log**

[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'compareImages'

dbug Support Initializing opencv

dbug Support Loading local package 'opencv4nodejs'

dbug Support Failed to load local package 'opencv4nodejs': Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs'

dbug Support Require stack:
dbug Support - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js

dbug Support - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js

dbug Support - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/build/lib/node.js

dbug Support - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/build/lib/image-util.js

dbug Support - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/build/index.js

dbug Support - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/logsink.js

dbug Support - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js

dbug Support Failed to load global package 'opencv4nodejs': The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

dbug Support Linking package 'opencv4nodejs'

[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Parsed BUILD_DIR configuration value: '/Users/-username-/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-(some data)/Build/Products'

[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Got derived data root: '/Users/-username-/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-(some data)'

dbug Support Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs', linking failed: Command 'npm link opencv4nodejs' exited with code 236

dbug Support npm ERR! code ENOTDIR

dbug Support npm ERR! syscall rename

dbug Support npm ERR! path /Users/-username-/node_modules/opencv4nodejs

dbug Support npm ERR! dest /Users/-username-/node_modules/.opencv4nodejs-YhDFjzvW

dbug Support npm ERR! errno -20

dbug Support npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, rename
'/Users/-username-/node_modules/opencv4nodejs' -> '/Users/-username-/node_modules/.opencv4nodejs-YhDFjzvW'

dbug Support

dbug Support npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

dbug Support npm ERR!     /Users/-username-/.npm/_logs/2021-11-02T08_10_14_713Z-debug.log
dbug Support

ERR! Support Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs': Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs', linking failed: Command 'npm link opencv4nodejs' exited with code 236

WARN Support Unable to load 'opencv4nodejs': Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs': Unable to load package 'opencv4nodejs', linking failed: Command 'npm link opencv4nodejs' exited with code 236

Answer (score 0):

Iam Facing same issues couple week a go ,I assume opnecv4nodejs not works properly on appium 1.20.xx , Here my solution :

Step By Step :

1. Un install opencv-build, opencv4nodejs and opencv:

```html
brew uninstall opecv
npm uninstall -g opencv-build
npm uninstall -g opencv4nodejs
```

2. Downgrade Appium to 1.20.xx

```html
sudo npm uninstall -g appium
sudo npm install -g appium@1.20.2 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root --force
sudo chown -R $(whoami) <path of Appium node modules> (e.g: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium)
```

3. Downgrade node to v10.16.1
   you can follow this step [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
   and please don't use nvm or make sure your node modules at usr/loca/lib/node_modules
4. set env variable to select opencv modules to install WITH autobuild

```html
export OPENCV4NODEJS_AUTOBUILD_FLAGS=-DBUILD_LIST=core,imgproc,imgcodecs,videoio,highgui,video,calib3d,features2d,objdetect,dnn,ml,flann,photo,stitching,gapi
```

5. Install opencv & opencv4nodejs

```html
npm i -g opencv-build
npm i -g opencv4nodejs
```